# Search builder operators do not work for Preferred Communication Method

Tags: issues, search-builder

You can reproduce this yourself on the demo site:

```
Search Builder > Contacts > Preferred Communication Method = Phone
```

Returns the *exact same* results as

```
Search Builder > Contacts > Preferred Communication Method != Phone
```

See the screenshots:

[image: equals]

and then:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found a bug.  Check out [Reporting a Bug](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting), starting with step 7.

As a point of interest - variations on this bug have been reported before. For instance, [CRM-6652](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-6652), several years ago, which was only fixed last month with [CRM-16483](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16483).

If you're looking to patch this yourself, I would definitely look to CRM-16483 as a model.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Jon. I'll file a bug ASAP and look at attempting a patch. Cheers.

Comment: @LinkSwanson - I was going through the issue tracker today, just wanted to make sure you were aware of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16286 so that you tried patching this on Civi 4.6.4+.

Comment: Can anyone think of a workaround that would allow me to create a smart group with communication method != Phone?

Comment: @LinkSwanson  Use Communication Preference IN ('Email', 'SMS', etc.)?

Comment: Thanks @JonG your suggestion worked on 4.6.3 ... then I upgraded to 4.6.4 and it no longer works. Using the `in` operator gives an error `Notice: Undefined index: IN in CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->preferredCommunication() (line 4007 of /srv/buildkit/build/d46/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php).` on the CiviCRM demo site. None of the operators work when using `Preferred Communication Method`. This bug is really hurting the reputation of CiviCRM within our organization.

Comment: @LinkSwanson That's completely understandable that it's hurting CiviCRM's reputation. CiviCRM is free to use, but not free to write - and given my own experiences, I suspect that the folks in whose eyes Civi's reputation is hurt are folks who aren't willing to pay for bug fixes. If I'm wrong, you may want to encourage them to help everyone - including themselves - by paying you to write the patch, or by submitting this to the paid issue queue: https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue